# [React Native][IOS] How to catch the event when the app is opened by a notification

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios

React Native has a PushNotificationIOS module to get the notification data and listen on events like `notificaiton`, `register`. I want to catch an event when the app is opened by a notification like: `PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification_open', myhandler);`. Is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

### 1. Use `PushNotificationIOS`

You can call `PushNotificationIOS.getInitialNotification();` at the point where it would matter. For example, you could call this method in your app's `index.js` file and decide which component to render. From [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html):

> This method returns a promise. If the app was launched by a push notification, this promise resolves to an object of type `PushNotificationIOS`. Otherwise, it resolves to `null`.

## 2. Use the native iOS App Delegate

From [the `UIApplicationDelegate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate):

> For example, if your app was launched because of an incoming remote notification, you might want to reconfigure your user interface to display data related to that notification. For a list of possible reasons why your app might be launched, see Launch Options Keys.

If you need to know earlier for some reason, you can check in the native `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` methods. Note that these methods are called before React Native is even initialized. This is a more advanced use case which most React Native apps don't need.

Comment: PushNotificationIOS.getInitialNotification() is called when a user taps the notification OR when he directly opens the app after a notification Was received in background. How do you differentiate between the two situations?